# java.jdbc clojure execute! insert arity

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, clojure

I'm working with a postgres database from clojure using java.jdbc.

```
[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.6.1"]
[org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1201-jdbc41"]
```

I want to do an 'upsert' operation on a database using some code like this:

```
 (if (-> updatesU count pos?) (sql/execute! spec ["insert into users(id, name) values (?, ?) on conflict(id) do update set name=EXCLUDED.name;"]  updatesU  {:multi? true} ))
 (if (-> updatesTE count pos?) (sql/execute! spec ["insert into time_entries(id, spent_date, hours, userid, project, task) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) on conflict(id) do update set spent_date=EXCLUDED.spent_date, hours=EXCLUDED.hours;"] updatesTE {:multi? true} )))
```

The documentation seems to have no examples so I'm sort of lost for a solution.

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (4) passed to: jdbc/execute!
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: It takes either 2 or 3 arguments, as per the documentation: https://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/#clojure.java.jdbc/execute!

Comment: Is your `if` supposed to have an else body? Do you have a misplaced brace? If it's not supposed to have an else body, `when` would be a better option so that's clear.

Answer (score 0):

The common case is that parameters to the statement go inside the vector as scalars:

```
(sql/execute! 
  spec 
  ["insert into users(id, name) values (?, ?) on conflict(id) do update set name=EXCLUDED.name;"  id name]  
  {:multi? false} ))
```

The { :multi? true } is when you are executing the statement multiple times, not a single time with multiple parameters, for instance:

```
(sql/execute!
  spec
  ["insert into users(id, name) values (?, ?) on conflict(id) do update set name=EXCLUDED.name;"  [id1 name1] [id2 name2] [id3 name3]]
  {:multi? true} ))
```

Some additional examples are here:

http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html

The clojure.java.jdbc library currently has a great, active, helpful maintainer but a confusing legacy API that predates modern idiom. A perhaps slightly more intuitive API is available through a newer jdbc library, called clojure.jdbc (as opposed to clojure.java.jdbc):

http://funcool.github.io/clojure.jdbc/latest/